# Does GarageBand let me record my own vocal/instrument region as a loop?

Tags: daw, garage-band

As a novice to DAWs I recently put together a recording of a song in Garageband. I wanted to record say 'chorus acoustic guitar' once and build the song structure using this multiple times.
All I could find was the ability to copy-paste it manually to each bar location - each copy was separate so if I wanted to re-record it or change the levels, I had to repeat the entire process.

Is this a feature I'm missing? I know 'loops' is a feature of GB but I have no experience with electronic music and am not sure if you can do this with custom recorded audio?

I am considering upgrading to a more serious DAW so as a side-question, do more powerful DAWs provide this?

Comment: idk Garage Band well enough, but many DAWs can use 'ghost' copies, so if the original changes, so do all the ghosts [or at least ask you keep/overwrite] See if a cmd drag or ctl or shift… changes the resulting copy.

Answer (score 1):

This link explains how to make an audio or software instrument region into a loop in GB. I tested it and it works:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25033?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

After creating one, it will appear in your library under the name you assign it.

Comment: Thanks John I had not realised you could do this. I'll investigate.

Comment: Just open the loop browser first then drag the region towards it and it’ll open up the window. There’s also an option to do it with a menu selection. If you click the loop box at the top the loop will tempo adjust to whichever song you import it  into.

Comment: Also, if GB does everything you need there’s no reason to change for now. Logic Pro is a full featured extension of GarageBand (GB even looks like Logic with a bunch of buttons and sliders missing, lol) but do some homework, there are a lot of great DAW’s available these days.